# Gradle dependencies: how to remove java classes from jar in repository?

Tags: gradle, dependencies

Grade: how to exclude some java classes from a jar in public repository?

For example, a foo.jar in repository depends on bar1.jar, bar2.jar

```
foo.jar
     bar1.jar
     bar2.jar
```

remove "javax/**" from foo.jar, add it into runtimeOnly configuration

```
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly foo-changed.jar, bar1.jar, bar2.jar
}
```

Tried

```
configurations {
     changeFoo
}

dependencies {
     changeFoo "group:foo:1.0"  // contains foo.jar, bar1.jar, bar2.jar
}

task changeFoo(type: Jar) {
    def jarFile = configurations.changeFoo.singleFile   // error: more than one file

    from zipTree(jarFile) {
        exclude 'javax/**'
    }

    destinationDir project.libsDir
    archiveName "foo-changed.jar"
}
```

How to get the single file (foo.jar)?
How to replace the foo.jar in the configurations.changeFoo with foo-changed.jar?

```
dependencies {
    runtimeOnly.extendsFrom changeFoo
}
```

Comment: i see you are asking loads of questions here about gradle, most of them are already answered on stack, or easy to find on google, did you consider doing some research, as well your questions are not clear and are not Minimal, Complete and Verifiable Examples please consider following those rules to help us to help you. BTW you asked 3 questions above and im not sure what you are trying to achieve

Comment: Actually I did some search before asking questions. I am totally new to Gradle for about 2 weeks.

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this.

```
configurations.changeFoo.asFileTree.each {
    from(zipTree(it))
    exclude ''
}
destinationDir project.libsDir
archiveName "foo-changed.jar"
```

Comment: exclude some java classes, not transitive dependencies.